# bulk files upload to document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

in one of the project we need to upload bulk files ( 250 mb at a time or more ) to a document library in SharePoint 2010. OOB multiple file upload through IE browser is not good one as it gives trouble.

what other approach is possible?

Is there any custom web part which can do this? any link for that code will be helpful.

Which 3rd party control is reliable for this & cost effective also?

Pl suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have to also agree on MetaVistech.com tool

But, if your looking for a good end user tool, you should look at Harmon.ie

Its a good Outlook plugin that you can drag/drop those files from your File Share into the SharePoint document library as seen from outlook.

go to http://harmon.ie to check out the Outlook plugin

Answer (score 1):

you can consider 3-rd party solution. For example from VirtoSoftware - [Bulk File Upload](http://www.virtosoftware.com/products/bulk/virto-bulk-file-upload)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether a web part would help. There are several third party applications for bulk uploading and metadata management of files into SharePoint. A quick web search for "Sharepoint bulk upload" will give you an idea.

We use a tool from [Metaviz](http://www.metavistech.com/category/sharepoint-users), but there are many others.

Before you embark on bulk uploading, make sure your SQL content databases are up the the task, have plenty of white space and don't auto-grow in chunks of 1MB. That would wreak havoc and lead to severe disk fragmentation.

Answer (score 0):

[here is](http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/) a codeplex free script giving you possibility to upload multiple files to SharePoint.

Try to [this](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/) tool that is Silverlight one and can be easily integrate to SharePoint using OOTB Silverlight web part. We have used this tool for SharePoint 2007 with minimal editing

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

agree with teylyn regarding the auto-grow.

it's possible to increase the the maximum upload size in Central Admin for each web app.  You could temporarily raise that limit and use Open With Explorer to copy/paste in bulk and reduce the max upload size when you finished with your implementation.  The upload will generally take a loooong time via this method.

A dedicated migration software tool will almost always do a better job of moving things as they are technically moving one file at a time but doing it repeatedly. This is much better for things like memory management on the system side.  You will also have many added advantages such as tagging metadata correctly.  I also use a branded version of the Metavis tool sold via Idera.  It has its quirks but for the most part does its job.